# Looking for Api to distinguish between personal account or business account

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-signin, google-contacts-api

I have a requirement from our client as follows, please point me in right direction.
I am trying to call sign in with Google, and looking for response in Oauth whether the user account is personal or Business account. I couldnt find this information anywhere, I have added profile scope in Oauth2.0 but still couldn't distinguish. Please let us know which API needs to be calle.